# how to change the entire background in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, bluetooth

[Open source code that I am using](http://@OmarAhmed%20I%20don't%20think%20there%20is%20a%20XML%20of%20the%20activity%20that%20displays%20the%20ListView.)

in my design render it shows me the entire background is blue but the actually app only have color on the listviews. Following is my xml code and screen shots.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#b8569fee">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#b8569fee"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#b8569fee"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

render
[image]

actually app:
[image]

I tried to change the textview layout height to match_parent, but it still didn't work, so what do i need to do to change the entire background?

Thnaks

Comment: You want to change the color of views or whole background?

Comment: @BOB show your layout where the listView is contained, see my answer.

Comment: You wrote that code in the template of the ListView and not in the actual XML of the activity which displays the List View .Instead add ` android:background="#b8569fee" ` inside <ListView instead

Comment: @Rohit B the whole background

Comment: @Jorgesys I don't have other layout for the listView.

Comment: @BOB The .xml file that is loaded via setContent() in your activity.

Comment: @OmarAhmed I don't think there is a XML of the activity that displays the ListView. I added the open source code that I am using in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that your XML file is defining the layout for an individual element in that list view, then the list view is programatically applying this XML to build a new view onto the list whenever a new BLE device is discovered. The size of each list element is defined externally, by whatever is putting each of your views into the list. Therefore, when you put match_parent in the LinearLayout and expect that to fix your issue, it does not because it only fills the area allotted by the listview. The fix is to change the background color within the listview itself, which is not done in this XML.

I'd need to see to more code to know exactly how to do this, but I am going to take a shot in the dark and assume that you are using a ListActivity, as in the [Google BluetoothLeGatt example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt). In this case, you can change the background color of the ListView using something like:

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(86, 159, 238));
```

Placed in the onCreate method.

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Would you mind point out where in the source code it sets the size of each list element?

What do I need to change if I want to use the xml file to change the background instead?

Comment: It's not so easy, since you are using ListActivity, the layout is defined by source code written by Google. Of course, you can override the layout of the ListActivity by using setContentView in OnCreate to define your own XML for it to use. See the section on [Screen Layout here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

The view indicated is only a view inside the layout that contains the `ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b8569fee">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#b8569fee"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#b8569fee"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**You must change the background color to the layout that contains the `ListView`**

```
 android:background="#b8569fee"
```